# Microservice/Distributed System: How to handle the scenario when uploading an image to a service fails but its info still exists in another service?

Tags: spring, microservices

I am building a website that contains a service that allows the users to upload an image with some additional info such as name and description via a form, and this is how I originally designed the process:

On form submitted(Vue.js) -> first upload the image info(id, name, description) to backend(Spring boot, in transaction mode) -> then upload the image itself to AWS S3.

The backend database table contains the id of the image that can be used to retrieve it from S3. After finishing the coding, I realized I did not handle the scenario where one of the service(S3, backend) fail, but the other service might have already saved info, resulting in data inconsistency. My original thought was that since all of this happen in a single function, I can simply exist the function if uploading to backend fails, and the code that upload the image to S3 would never be triggered. However, to deal with the scenario where uploading to backend successes but to S3 fails, my original thought was to simply make another request to backend to remove the dirty data, but I am not sure if there is a more elegant way to deal with this. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data consistency across multiple services is handled by transactions.

The solution you suggested with informing backend about failed uploads so it can remove them from the database is one way to handle it - however there's a more verbose approach that works better, and it goes like this:

1. Form is submitted. Backend gets info about the upload and sets its status to "pending" in the database - this should be a dedicated column.
2. Upload to AWS S3 is performed - whether it fails or not - it sets status of the upload to "committed" or "failed".
3. A background job is periodically cleaning up the database from "failed" entries, or you can remove them when the status is set. The solution may vary from database to database - some like numerous small queries, other prefer chunks.

This is better because you'll avoid data discrepancies during the time between information landing in the backend and the actual outcome of the upload.
FYI: This is called a 2PC (two-phase commit) pattern - if you want to read more on that.

You should also look into sagas.